# Silverlight 4 printing and element visibility

Tags: silverlight, printing, visibility

I am printing two identical "labels" from a dialog (a ChildWindow) but want only one to be visible on the actual dialog. Sounds easy enough, code both in the XAML and have the visibility of the element containing the second collapsed initially, then set it visible while printing. Except the results are not as expected.

If I don't collapse the second label so it is visible on the dialog all the time it prints as expected but when I hide the second the print doesn't have two copies of the label; rather the elements of the second are overlaid over the first as shown below.

[image]

Here is the XAML that I'm printing

```
<Border x:Name="PrintRange" BorderBrush="#00000000" BorderThickness="20">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Border x:Name="FirstCopy" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" CornerRadius="5">
            <Grid Margin="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Source="/MiX.DLD.Web.UI.Silverlight;component/Images/VdoLogo.png" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="DLD" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                 Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="IMPORTANT NUMBERS" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                                 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                <TextBlock Text="IMEI NUMBER" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="2" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImeiNumber,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="SERIAL NUMBER" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="3" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SerialNumber,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="REGISTRATION CODE" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="4" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RegistrationCode,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <Border x:Name="SecondCopy" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" CornerRadius="5" 
                        Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <Grid Margin="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Source="/MiX.DLD.Web.UI.Silverlight;component/Images/VdoLogo.png" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="DLD" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                 Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="IMPORTANT NUMBERS" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                                 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                <TextBlock Text="IMEI NUMBER" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="2" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImeiNumber,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="SERIAL NUMBER" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="3" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SerialNumber,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="REGISTRATION CODE" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="4" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RegistrationCode,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

and here is the method in which I do the printing

```
private void OnPrintButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var pd = new PrintDocument();
  pd.PrintPage += (s, args) =>
                    {
                      SecondCopy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                      args.PageVisual = PrintRange;
                    };
  pd.EndPrint += (s, args) => { SecondCopy.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; };
  pd.Print("MiX DLD pre-registration label");

  this.DialogResult = true;
}
```

I can solve the problem by moving the setting of SecondCopy.Visibility out of the PrintPage event handler and placing it above the pd.Print() call but this visibly updates the screen before the dialog closes and looks messy, so I'd prefer not to do it this way.

Any suggestions on how I might resolve this problem?